# Aligning inputs on bootstrap using the Fluid Grid System

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am creating a form that requires the user to input their name and email address. The first line of the form has two inputs side by side for each part of the name and the 2nd line has one input for the email address that should be the same width as the first line combined. I'm trying to use the fluid grid system but can't line up the 2nd row with the first.

```
<form action="/subscriptions" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
       <div class="controls row-fluid">
          <input class="span2" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First" required="required" type="text">
          <input class="span2" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last" required="required" type="text">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <div class="controls row-fluid">
      <input class="span4" id="email" name="email" type="email">
    </div>
   </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sguha095/v4amX/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look a this jdfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kY5LL/18/

I added some `div.row-fluid` containers per row of your form and one extra set of inputs for demonstration.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem here. The latest release includes a new class `.controls-row` for this very purpose. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in fluid layouts yet (as of version 2.1.1). But a fix #5039 has been added and will probably be in the next release. Looking at your argument from this point of view, it seems, that the official documentation actually does favor mixing grids and forms.

Comment: You're correct that it doesn't work for fluid layouts (yet). When it does work for fluid layouts I still wouldn't use it. Reminds me of a quote from Jurassic Park, "we spend so much time trying to figure out if we can, that we stop to think if we should". Another way to look at it is this, you could add pull-left and pull-right, which are utility classes, on every single element that has a float. but that's just bad practice. It's not intended. Sometimes these classes are best used during prototyping then replaced with "real" semantic code after you get your layout working. But to each his own

Answer (score 2):

First we need to clean up the HTML a bit, there is an extra closing div on the first line.

I just added some classes to improve the styling so you could see how it works. The  `input-block-level` class is a bootstrap mixin to force inputs to act like true block level elements. That's needed if you want this to be clean and to leverage the benefits of CSS. If you want to do all of your styling with HTML, then you can do so with more markup and less semantic methods, but I would recommend against it.

Hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/kY5LL/12/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but s there anyway to do it using the Fluid Grid System http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem?

Comment: Very simple to do. I wouldn't clutter up the form with grid classes, it's not needed. The form is responsive with a simple media query to make the inputs 100% width at 480px and below. Check out the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kY5LL/12/   This way you can drop it in anywhere in the grid.

Comment: by the way, that should have been a second question technically. Did I answer your first question correctly?

Comment: You're answer definitely works, but I really wanted a answer that used the grid system to avoid maintaining my own CSS. Sorry I didn't phrase that clearly in the question, but I mentioned it before the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, you misunderstand how grids work. That's okay. Grids are for structure, not for the components that fit within that structure. The form is a component, you shouldn't mix grid code in with the component or you will make it more difficult to change any markup or css surrounding the form.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but it feels like your solution is repeating some of the work handled by the grid layout. For example, on a small screen (i.e. mobile browser) the fluid grid system will lay out each input on it's own line, but having that functionality in the solution you provided will duplicate css logic (such as the media queries) unnecessarily.

Comment: It's the opposite, the grid already works on the layout around the form. The idea is to "wrap" the form with grid markup so that the form can just fluidly adjust to whatever happens to the grid around it. Adding additional grid markup inside the form is unnecessary, complicates the form, and adds (a lot) of additional baggage in terms of inherited properties on the element that aren't needed.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that Mark Otto, creator of bootstrap has a form example in the docs/examples folder, called signin.html. Check it out. It doesn't have inline inputs, as in my example, but it doesn't use grid markup at all, because it keeps control of the form in the CSS - not the HTML, and it's ultimately less complicated.

Comment: In fact, looking through the source, I can see that provisions were made to use the grid system on form elements directly https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/70b1a6b56213bf9317c62784cd1a45c1c7290bb5/lib/forms.less#L242, leading me to believe that this is what the authors intended.

Comment: Here is a test case written by Mark Otto showcasing the grid layouts inside a form https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/364dbb7931393cb8fa796d75ec1f32a757d335e1

Comment: the authors of bootstrap emphasize over and over not to just use the examples, but to use bootstrap as a starting point. We can cite examples to demonstrate both use cases, many times over. You asked for help with this, which indicates that you don't have enough css knowledge to decide the right way to go without documentation. I offered my advice based on knowledge I do have of CSS and Twitter Bootstrap (which I have contributed to). You can certainly use the "straight out of the box, pasted from bootstrap docs" code if you wish, it's valid. There are just better ways. Best of luck